# "Jamie and me" or "Jamie and I"

Tags: grammar

Please let me know which sentence is proper?

> Summer has always been an imaginative time for Jamie and me.
>   
> Summer has always been an imaginative time for Jamie and I.

Comment: Would you say "imaginative for we" or "imaginative for us" ?  I think this answers your question.

Comment: Take out "Jamie and" and see which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I" is a subject pronoun and "me" is an object pronoun.
So, the correct usage would be the second option:
"Summer was a magical time for Jamie and me".